# <p:blockUI> does not respond on <h:commandButton><f:ajax>

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, commandbutton, blockui

I got a `<h:commandButton` like:

```
<h:commandButton id="login"
  actionListener="#{bean.login}" value="Login"
  styleClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
   <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

and a

`<p:blockUI id="block" block=":form" trigger="login" />`

It is not working. The block is never shown up.

It does work with a `<p:commandButton>`.

How can I achieve it with a `<h:commandbutton>`. If that is not possible: Is there any workaround?

Comment: Did you try an `h:commandButton` with `p:ajax`?

Comment: Oh, I missed your comment. See the accepted answer. :)

Comment: Yes, I already noticed. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<p:blockUI>` listens on PrimeFaces/jQuery-specific `pfAjaxSend` and `pfAjaxComplete` events only. Those events are triggered by all PrimeFaces ajax components, but not by standard JSF `<f:ajax>`.

You've 3 options:

1. Replace `<f:ajax>` by `<p:ajax>` to let the `<h:commandButton>` send a PF/jQuery ajax request instead of a standard JSF one.

   ```
   <h:commandButton id="login" value="Login" action="#{bean.login}">
       <p:ajax process="@form" update="@form" />
   </h:commandButton>
   ```

   *(note: carefully read [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener/))*

   ---
2. Attach a global listener on `<f:ajax>` which auto-triggers the PF/jQuery-specific events.

   ```
   jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(function(data) {
       if (data.status === "begin") {
           $(document).trigger("pfAjaxSend", [null, data]);
       }
       else if (data.status === "success") {
           $(document).trigger("pfAjaxComplete", [null, data]);
       }
   });
   ```

   Might have some undesired side-effects, though.

   ---
3. Manually trigger a specific `<p:blockUI>` during `<f:ajax>` events.

   ```
   <f:ajax ... onevent="triggerBlockUI" />
   ...
   <p:blockUI widgetVar="widgetBlockUI" ... />
   ```

   With this JS function.

   ```
   function triggerBlockUI(data) {
       if (data.status === "begin") {
           PF("widgetBlockUI").show();
       }
       else if (data.status === "success") {
           PF("widgetBlockUI").hide();
       }
   }
   ```

   ---

Needless to say that option 1 is the most straightforward choice.

Answer (score 0):

Try p:commandlink Instead. I had the same problem for h:commandlink and its solved