# OmniFaces highlight does not set focus with <p:ajax>

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, omnifaces

I got a simple login form. I am using `<p:ajax>` to invoke a `<p:blockUI>` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29683262/pblockui-does-not-respond-on-hcommandbuttonfajax) question).

```
<h:commandButton id="anmeldung_button"
action="#{benutzerAnmeldung.anmelden}" value="Anmelden"
styleClass="btn btn-info btn-sm">
    <p:ajax process="@form" update="@form"/>
</h:commandButton>
<p:blockUI id="block" block=":anmeldung" trigger="anmeldung_button" />
```

I am using `<o:highlight />` to highlight invalid inputs. This works fine.
It is working with a `<f:ajax>` perfectly, too.

Apperently, it is not working with `<p:ajax>`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by `<p:ajax>` trying to refocus the active element *after* executing the oncomplete scripts via `doEval()` (as can be seen in [`handleReFocus()` function in `core.ajax.js` script](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/5_2/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/core/core.ajax.js#L610). However, when you submit the form by clicking the command button instead of pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> while inside the input, then that active element becomes the command button itself, not the input text. You can confirm this by just using <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to submit the form. You'll see that the focus is done right.

There are in your particular case 2 ways to workaround this:

1. Make use of PrimeFaces' own autofocus facility via `<p:focus>` which is placed inside the form as below:

   ```
   <h:form id="anmeldung">
       <p:focus context="anmeldung" />
       ...
   </h:form>
   ```

   It also automatically takes into account invalidated input fields.
2. Set `PrimeFaces.customFocus` to `true` in JavaScript, so that `handleReFocus()` function won't do its job.

   ```
   <script>PrimeFaces.customFocus = true;</script>
   ```

Comment: It is working perfectly. I am using `onfocus="this.value=this.value"` in additon, to the cursor to the right position.

Comment: Perhaps PF11 so is beter : ((HtmlInputText) element).setOnfocus("const v = this.value; this.value = ''; this.value = v;");